# Why won't my external device connect to my Android device via serial-to-USB?

Tags: android, serial-port, usb

I have the following setup:

[image: External Device with RS232 M, connected to Cable 1 with RS232 F to RS232 F, connected to Cable 2 with RS232 M to USB-A M, connected to Android Device with USB-A F]

However, when rverything is connected, I open my terminal and run `adb shell lsusb`, but I don't see any change between before or after I plug Cable 2 into the Android Device. **What do I have to do to get the Android Device to detect the signals coming from the External Device to the Android Device?**

---

- The External Device and the Android Device are *not* OTS hardware.
- The Android Device regularly interacts with other hardware via its USB-A ports, but these devices have native USB-A cables.

  - I have ensured that Cable 2 is not plugged into a debug-only USB-A port, and have tried it in all of the Android Device's other ports.
- The External Device regularly interacts with other hardware via its RS232 port, but these have native serial ports.
- I have tried restarting the External Device and the Android Device while the cables were plugged in and unplugged

Comment: If there is a better SE for this, please direct me there or migrate it.

Comment: *"Cable 1"* should probably be wired as "null modem", i.e. RxD and TxD swapped.  If it is, then try a straight-through cable. BTW *"Cable 2"* is not simply a cable but an *adapter* with active electronics; it's a USB device.  So plug this USB adapter in first, and make sure it's initialized by the (USB host) *"Android device"*.  Once you get the proper electrical connections, then you have to configure the serial link parameters (baud rate, data length, parity, and stop bit length) to match on both ends.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for the response! Sorry I couldn't reply until now. I got a Null Modem adapter and put that in between Cable 1 and Cable 2, but that seemingly had no effect.
I plugged in Cable 2 alone (not connected to anything else), but I still see no change in `adb shell lsusb`.
How do I configure the serial link parameters from within an Android app?

Comment: What is this "external device"?  *"I plugged in Cable 2 alone (not connected to anything else)"* -- Why do you expect anything if there is no device on the other end of the serial link?  *"How do I configure the serial link parameters from within an Android app?"* -- An app that uses a serial port could have either a fixed config or a configuration interface.  Or try using **stty** before running the app.  Or use a *terminal emulation program* like **minicom**.

Comment: @sawdust Sorry, the details of the External Device and Android Device are classified. I expected something because you said _"'Cable 2' is not simply a cable but an adapter with active electronics; it's a USB device."_ (so is it or isn't it a device?). I'm attempting to allow our app to communicate out a USB-A port to a RS232-connected device, and also [want to set a custom config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743655/how-do-i-configure-com-settings-on-android). Can you elaborate on using `stty` or **minicom**? I.E. would those affect all USB ports or just the one I'm targeting?

Comment: I don't care about the details of your *"classified external device"*.  But what kind of device does it resemble?  Does it send text or binary data?  Is there a message protocol in place (e.g. you need an app to communicate)?  Or does it constantly send data (e.g. a weight scale)?  Don't you know how to generalize a problem?  A USB-to-RS232 adapter is a device, but it doesn't generate its own data.  It's a communication device, just like an Ethernet port; there are methods to read the device's *status*, but there's no *data* to read unless it's connected and data is being received.

Comment: @sawdust it sends ASCII data, and sometimes binary values alongside that. There is no app, API, or driver; that is what I am writing. It sends data when it has new data to send, otherwise it assumes you've kept track of the old data to know its state. Thank you for letting me know more about my USB-to-RS232 cable!